# Incorrect items' quantity and total sum in cart when adding more than 1 item

Tags: magento2, addtocart

I've just noticed a very strange issue-if I try to add more than one item to cart, then total quantity is always -1 to real quantity and Total sum consist of doubled prices of every added item apart from the last one. I checked this issue on guest user.

I changed my theme to Magento Blank in order to exclude theme related issues. Nothing changes.

I created two modules to call an external API on sales_order_save after event. I disabled them too, nothing happens.

At the same time, if you confirm an order, on admin panel all related information about a quantity of order's items and total sum of an order is displayed correctly.

What could be a possible reason for such behavior?

Thank you in advance for any clues.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So if you reverted back to the base Magento "blank" theme, and disabled extensions/custom code, then it's very likely something with inventory/product settings isn't working.

###### For example, this product might be broken or need changes:

`Notebook 15.4 "Fujitsu Siemens Intel Core 2 Duo T5750 2.0GHz / RAM 2Gb / HDD 250Gb / video Intel GMA X3100 / DWD-RW`

###### Just a few things I found on the site:

- It says it's in stock on product detail page, but doesn't add to cart from there
- It will sometimes add to cart from product list page, but not increase total product count
- It gives a message about `"Requested qty isn't available"` when it says in stock

###### Lastly, I haven't found any product that I can add more than 1 to cart without error.

- If you download the Magento sample product data you can look at how they create products to mimic their product types
- [Install Sample Product Data Docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/sample-data-after-magento.html)
- [Install Sample Data Blog](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-2-sample-data/)

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: It's turned out that the cause of such strange behavior was my another custom module that forces shipping and billing addresses be the same during a process of checkout. 

After disabling this "bad behaved" module I am searching for a solution how to hide "My billing and shipping address are the same" checkbox and corresponding form below on "Review & Payment" tab of Checkout page.

The goal is to free gest users from a duty to fill Shipping and Billing address forms. Special custom plugin fills in corresponding fields with some filler data (f.e. Street: No information) and hides fields.

Comment: Then  "My billing and shipping address are the same" checkbox is ticked by default. So, no need for a guest customer to fill in any address form. All that I need-to hide "My billing and shipping address are the same" checkbox and corresponding form below.

Thank you.